# PyMongo decorator variable to context of function

Tags: python

How can I pass a value into the context of a function from this decorator? Lets say `authStr` as an example.

```
# decorator for endpoints that need auth token
def requires_auth(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        authStr = request.headers.get('Authorization') # 'Bearer thisisatokenstrhere'
        check_auth(authStr) # check if expired
        if not check_auth(authStr):
            return abort(401)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the kwargs dict, you can simply add it there:

```
kwargs['authStr'] = authStr
return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

Although I don't know how useful that will be, unless the decorated function is already expecting that kwarg.